# How to use PERCENTILE_CONT without over clause? any alternative to it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am interested in finding median of an entire column in SQL Server and I don't want to partition/subset column based on some other attribute. I am looking for a way to use PERCENTILE_CONT without over or any other function to find median. I have tried

```
over(my_table)
OVER (PARTITION BY NULL)
OVER ( NULL)
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is your friend. There are examples for your reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @Fakhar the syntax for MS SQL is slightly different.

```
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) OVER()
```

---

For BigQuery SQL

```
PERCENTILE_CONT(your_field, 0.5) OVER()
```

Comment: The PERCENTILE_CONT function requires 1 argument(s). It should be PERCENTILE_CONT( 0.5)OVER() . It would return the same median in N rows, we can use select distinct if we are only selecting median. I took a small break and figured it out.

Comment: Ah thanks - the syntax above is for BigQuery SQL. I will update the answer.